# Angular Guards lifecycle clarification

Tags: angular, angular-guards

I was trying to find any information on the lifecycle application initialization. 
There are few types of guards. I'm interested in following types:

- CanActivate
- CanLoad
- CanActivateChild

Suppose we have following route configuration:

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: ParentA,
    canActivate: [CanActivateGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'childA',
        component: ChildA,
        canActivateChild: [CanActiveChildGuard]
      },
  }
```

and Main Routing:

```
{

      {
        path: 'parent',
        loadChildren: '@app/modules/parent.module#ParentModule',
        canLoad: [CanLoad]
      },
}
```

Now, when trying to open `parent/childA`. Which guard will be executed first?
Will `ParentA Component` be rendered before the CanActivateChildGuard check?

Answer (score 1):

The order should be:

1. CanLoad
2. CanActivateGuard
3. CanActiveChildGuard

You can see more info in the console by enabling the tracing for the router as following during initialization:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: false })
```

Comment: Will ParentA Component be rendered before the CanActivateChildGuard check?

Comment: that's an interesting question, you could easily verify it by adding logs into the constructor of the parent and the child component. Going by logic, I would definitely say yes: the parent should load, then the child route should be evaluated and then loaded. By the way I could be wrong: could be that angular evaluate all the parent and child routing before loading anything. That's why I suggest to enable tracing and checkout the logs.